# If statements not executing after function call in bash

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I have a bash script that looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

function run_container {
    CONTAINER_NAME=$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 16)
    echo "running: docker run -i --name $CONTAINER_NAME $REGISTRY/${1}"
    docker run -i --name $CONTAINER_NAME $REGISTRY"/"${1}
    echo "removing: container $CONTAINER_NAME from ${1}"
    docker container rm $CONTAINER_NAME
    echo "removing:  image $1"
    docker image rm ${REGISTRY}"/"${1}
    echo -e "\nDone with container ${1}\n\n\n"
    return 0
}


GCC_BUILD=${1}
GLIBC_BUILD=${2}
KERNEL_BUILD=${3}
POSTGRESQL_BUILD=${4}
PYTHON_BUILD=${5}
REINSTALL_PACKAGES=${6}
RUBY_BUILD=${7}
SEGMENTED_DOWNLOAD=${8}
UBUNTU_RSYNC=${9}


echo $GCC_BUILD
echo $GLIBC_BUILD
echo $KERNEL_BUILD
echo $POSTGRESQL_BUILD
echo $PYTHON_BUILD
echo $REINSTALL_PACKAGES
echo $RUBY_BUILD
echo $SEGMENTED_DOWNLOAD
echo $UBUNTU_RSYNC

REGISTRY="myregistry.com"


if [[ "$GCC_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running GCC_BUILD"
    run_container "gcc-build"
fi

if [[ "$GLIBC_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running GLIBC_BUILD"
    run_container "glibc-build"
fi

if [[ "$KERNEL_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running KERNEL_BUILD"
    run_container "kernel-build"
fi

if [[ "$POSTGRESQL_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running POSTGRESQL_BUILD"
    run_container "postgresql-build"
fi

if [[ "$PYTHON_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running PYTHON_BUILD"
    run_container "python-build"
fi

if [[ "$REINSTALL_PACKAGES" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running REINSTALL_PACKAGES"
    run_container "reinstall-packages"
fi

if [[ "$RUBY_BUILD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running RUBY_BUILD"
    run_container "ruby-build"
fi

if [[ "$SEGMENTED_DOWNLOAD" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running SEGMENTED_DOWNLOAD"
    run_container segmented-download
fi

if [[ "$UBUNTU_RSYNC" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Running UBUNTU_RSYNC"
    run_container "ubuntu-rsync"
fi

echo "Finished build suite."
```

Once an if statement matches, the function executes, but the script ends. So for example if the `GCC_BUILD` and `GLIBC_BUILD` variables are true, the script will perform the actions in the `run_container` function for the `GCC_BUILD`, but not for the `GLIBC_BUILD`.

If I remove the `run_container` call within the `if` statements, and just leave the `echo` there, everything runs as it should.

Is there something about the function that makes the script exit?

**UPDATE**:

Since I have `set -x` on here is what gets printed for trace:

```
:18+GCC_BUILD=false
:19+GLIBC_BUILD=false
:20+KERNEL_BUILD=false
:21+POSTGRESQL_BUILD=false
:22+PYTHON_BUILD=true
:23+REINSTALL_PACKAGES=false
:24+RUBY_BUILD=true
:25+SEGMENTED_DOWNLOAD=false
:26+UBUNTU_RSYNC=false
:29+echo false
:30+echo false
:31+echo false
:32+echo false
:33+echo true
:34+echo false
:35+echo true
:36+echo false
:37+echo false
:39+ARTIFACTORY=myregistry
:42+[[ false == \t\r\u\e ]]
:47+[[ false == \t\r\u\e ]]
:52+[[ false == \t\r\u\e ]]
:57+[[ false == \t\r\u\e ]]
:62+[[ true == \t\r\u\e ]]
:63+echo 'Running PYTHON_BUILD'
Running PYTHON_BUILD
running: docker run -i --name OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy myregistry/image
:64+run_container python-build
::6+date +%s
::6+sha256sum
::6+base64
::6+head -c 16
:6+CONTAINER_NAME=OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy
:7+echo 'running: docker run -i --name OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy myregistry/image'
:8+docker run -i --name OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy myregistry/image

Done with container python-build

:9+echo 'removing: container OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy from python-build'
:10+docker container rm OTQ0YzJjZTU4YWQy
:11+echo 'removing:  image python-build'
:12+docker image rm myregistry/image
:13+echo -e '\nDone with container python-build\n\n\n'
:14+return 0
```

I cannot post all output since there is a lot, but these are the lines that print from xtrace

Comment: You're collecting `xtrace` logs. Can you show them here? Even better would be to build a [mcve], the *shortest possible code* that generates the same problem.

Comment: BTW, the issues it'll detect don't look likely to be a cause of your immediate problem, but please run through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the quoting problems it identifies.

Comment: (It's also noteworthy that the ksh `function funcname {` syntax, back on legacy ksh, makes variables defined with `declare` in a function local-by-default, but it *doesn't* do that in bash; in bash, all it does is make your code incompatible with POSIX, which requires `funcname() {`).

Comment: You have a `[[ true == \t\r\u\e ]]` that **isn't** followed by an immediate function execution. Would you mind setting `PS4=':$LINENO+'` and updating your `set -x` log to include line numbers?

Comment: BTW, an `echo -e` that complies with the letter of the POSIX standard writes `-e` on output. Bash's `echo` is *often* noncompliant with that standard in a manner you're depending on, but not *always* noncompliant; its behavior depends on the `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags, and can be modified at compile-time, at runtime via `shopt`, or at runtime via environment variables. Best to follow the advice in the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the `echo` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) and use `printf` instead.

Comment: ...btw, if you want to distinguish shells invoked by `docker run`, you might make it `PS4=':$$:$BASHPID:${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'` or such; that way we're tracking new parent shells, new subshells, alternate source files, &c.

Comment: Hmm. What's the output of `echo "$-"`, when run from inside your script?

Comment: BTW, one place I would start is looking at whether `docker run -i` breaks your terminal. Running it with `</dev/null` so it can't consume stdin is one useful place to start. As a temporary debugging measure, piping its stdout and stderr to a non-TTY FIFO, like `cat`, may also be illustrative (and if they're not, well, no harm done). That is: `docker run ... </dev/null > >(cat) 2>&1`, or such.

Comment: BTW, if you want to separate the xtrace logs from the others, on bash 4.0+ you can redirect them to a file descriptor other than stderr. Put `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>xtrace.log` in your script in bash 4.1 or later; it'll open the file for write and put the FD number in the variable `BASH_XTRACEFD`, which is honored by bash in determining where to write xtrace logs to.

Comment: Your trace doesn't match the code you posted. (It indicates a variable `ARTIFACTORY` was set, not a variable `REGISTRY`, and the value is different, too.)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you make the `</dev/null` comment the answer, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script unexpectedly stops executing after a program that -- like `ssh`, `ffmpeg`, or `docker run -i` -- can read stdin or modify terminal configuration, one step you want to run in debugging is to redirect that program's stdin from `/dev/null`.

To do that (and address some issues with names having spaces in the process), change:

```
docker run -i --name $CONTAINER_NAME $REGISTRY"/"${1}
```

to:

```
docker run -i --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" "$REGISTRY/$1" </dev/null
```

...or, if you need to isolate the command from the terminal more completely, you can (at some efficiency cost) give it a non-TTY stdout and stderr:

```
docker run -i --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" "$REGISTRY/$1" </dev/null > >(cat) 2>&1
```

...though I'd usually remove `-i` before going that far.

Comment: the return was there because I was trying things. It still doesn't work, I updated the post accordingly

Comment: in the process of doing that

Comment: can you just plop an example of the `docker run ... </dev/null > >(cat) 2>&1` because that's what fixed it for me

Comment: If that's the fix you need, it might be appropriate to take out the `-i`.

Comment: Oops, I missed that I'd left out the `</dev/null` when writing this! BTW, "Community Wiki" answers are considered owned by the community -- the original author doesn't get any personal reputation, and the norm is that there's no need to check in before doing edits yourself so long as you're sure that they make the answer more helpful.